# Find the Limit of the given sequence x_n = $(1 - 1/3 )^2$ $(1 - 1/6)^2$ $(1 - 1/10)^2$...$(1 - 2/n(n+1))^2$, $n\geq2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

$x_n = \left(1 - \dfrac13 \right)^2\left(1 - \dfrac16\right)^2\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{10}\right)^2\cdots\left(1 - \dfrac{2}{n(n+1)}\right)^2, n\ge2$

Then find lim of (x_n) as n tends to infinity.

I have deduced that the given sequence is Monotonic (Decreasing) and Bounded (between 0 and 1). So by Monotone Convergence theorem it must converge to the infimum of the set of all values of the sequence.

I am not able to proceed any further. The options given are:

(A) 1/3, (B) 1/9, (C) 1/81, (D) 0. I have eliminated the first two options based on the fact that it is easy to identify terms of the sequence with values less than 1/3 or 1/9.

I am stuck with the last two options. I think the answer should be 0. But how do I eliminate the option (C) with a good logical argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $$1-\frac{2}{n(n+1)} = \frac{n^2+n-2}{n(n+1)} = \frac{(n+2)(n-1)}{n(n+1)} = \frac{\dfrac{n-1}{n+1}}{\dfrac{n}{n+2}}$$

Comment: This clearly tends to 1. But the nth term is a product of terms with this being the last term. How do I take that product into account?

Comment: Let $g(n)=\left(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\right)^2$. Then the product is $$\frac{g(2)}{g(3)}\frac{g(3)}{g(4)}\dots \frac{g(n-1)}{g(n)}$$ Can you see how easy this is?

Comment: Yes! Finally I do see it. Thanks a lot :)